# Can't push git commit to remote branch after stg import

Tags: git, svn, version-control, github

I can't seem to commit a change in my local branch back to the remote branch.

The local branch (26f)  is tracking the remote branch (origin/fixes/0.26) on github via ssh.

I imported a change using stg import which commited the fix to my local branch as shown by git status:

```
git status
# On branch 26f
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/fixes/0.26' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

But, when I run git push, it says there is nothing to push:

```
git push
Everything up-to-date
```

Per the "Tracking Branches" section of http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches git push should work as it states "If you’re on a tracking branch and type git push, Git automatically knows which server and branch to push to"

Was originally getting this error with git 1.7.3.4.  Have upgraded to 1.8.3.2 and am seeing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

So this appears to have worked:

```
git push git@github.com:me/it.git 26f:fixes/0.26
```

but it still seems to contradict with the "Tracking Branches" section of http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Branching-Remote-Branches